# ESLint error on semicolon after class declaration ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lint, babeljs

I have the following code:

```
class Car() {

    constructor() {
        // ...
    }

    withSemi() {
        // ...
    };  // ESLint does not complain here

    withoutSemi() {
       // ...
    }  // ESLint does not complain here

};  // ESLint will complain about this semicolon (no-extra-semi)
```

Can someone explain how the automatic semicolon insertion will work in ES6 in regards to classes and why ESLint has this behaviour?

Comment: From what I understand, the semantics of `class` are similar to `function` wrt no semicolon i.e. `class name {}` and `function name() {}`, so ESLint would be correct with its warning.

Comment: Then how can the semicolons after methods be explained? (ESLint does not care if I add them or not).

Comment: From what I can see `methods` are defined without the keyword `function` and like `function` should not end `;`. But expressions like `public numAttacks = 0;` should end with `;` So pretty much like how you would expect javascript to be written pre ES6

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ECMAScript 2015 `class` specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions), a semicolon is a valid `ClassElement`, so it can exist within a `ClassBody`.

However, its semantics treat it as having no behavior whatsoever (for example, see [`NonConstructorMethodDefinitions`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-nonconstructormethoddefinitions)). **Effectively you can have as many or as few semicolons you want in a `ClassBody` and it won't change a thing.**

Automatic semicolon insertion actually doesn't come into play here, or as often as people think in general. Roughly speaking, ASI only happens when the parser sees something that **wouldn't be allowed** to be part of the previous block or line. (The [actual rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) for ASI aren't terribly long if you're interested; scroll down for examples and practical advice.) However in this context, you're allowed to put a bunch of class method definitions together sequentially. Thus there's nothing "unexpected" about the next method in the list, so no semicolon gets inserted between them.

I don't know the history of the decision, but I assume semicolons are valid `ClassElement`s because they were already valid as empty statements, and it would probably be confusing for folks if you *couldn't* put semicolons in a class body.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but by looking at the ESLint [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-semi) I would have expected it to complain about the extra semis inside the class body.

Comment: Actually, looking at the [source of the rule](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/no-extra-semi.js), it's definitely supposed to catch semis in class bodies. Have you set `ecmaVersion` to 6 or higher in your config? Otherwise ESLint won't use `class` rules...